# GRASS 7.3 r.fill.dir Does Not Create Output Raster

Tags: raster, grass-gis, analysis

I am running GRASS 7.3 on Mac OS X El Capitan (2.9GHz, 8GB RAM).  I have had to disable SIP in order to run it, but it works. I am hoping to perform some hydrological analyses on a few DEMs. My DEMs are 5ft resolution county-scale rasters totaling a few GB apiece but I have performed lots of large-raster operations (outside of GRASS) on this machine with no issues.

When I run r.fill.dir, everything goes smoothly at first; the input raster loads quickly and within the first 5 minutes or so the first two sets of downward/upward passes have completed. Downward pass 3 takes several hours(~5.5 - 6.5) before the command apparently finishes successfully. However, when I look for the output rasters, they do not exist.

I have tried this multiple times, including with a reprojected version of the raster. Same result each time. I always make sure to set the region to match my raster before running the command.

Comment: How big is the region? Can you try on a small subset of DEM (say 1000x1000 pixels)?

Comment: The region is pretty big — 22609 x 50989. Not sure how this compares in the scheme of things, but it is a countywide raster after all.

I tried your suggestion and used g.region to set a smaller region extent (~5000 x 5000 cells). `r.fill.dir` completed succesfully in just a couple of minutes.

The interesting thing (to me) is that `r.fill.dir` does not crash and claims to finish successfully when I run it on the entire raster. Not sure what this would mean. Could it be a memory issue? I thought 8gb would be adequate

Comment: Note that a region of 22,000 X 51,000 is >1.1 billion cells. The module produces both elevation (probably Float32 ?) and direction maps. So each will be several gigabytes. You might indeed be running out of memory. Are you sure you need such high resolution for a country scale?

Comment: I am interested in assessing sinkholes on a county level, so it would be ideal to be able to maintain the original resolution, and to be able to run it as one raster vs having to do it in pieces… even though it does seem (based on my testing of smaller extents) that it might be significantly faster to process the county in portions by adjusting the region in GRASS.

Comment: After trying the same process on a region of ~450 million cells, I had similar results — it took less time than my attempts at processing the whole raster, but about 52 minutes to finish all in all. And no output raster to be found. If this is indeed a memory issue, which would seem to make sense, is there anything I might do (like memory allocation or something) which could improve performance or allow the process finish successfully?

Comment: Did you try a test on a much smaller region? only 1 million cells for example.

Comment: Yes, I did. Processing was very quick — I was able to process a region of about 25 million cells in under a minute. Output rasters loaded successfully